# Router Link not loading Component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm trying to send a Param via the URL and the app is not loading the component

I have my link looking like

```
<td><router-link :to="'/ledger/detail/' + Ledger.sequence"><samp>{{Ledger.sequence}}</samp></router-link></td>
```

My router looks like so

```
import LedgerDetail from './views/LedgerDetails/LedgerDetail.vue';

{
    path: "ledger/detail/:ledgerId",
    name:"ledger",
    component: LedgerDetail,
    props: true
}
```

and the URL has the id appended but it's not loading the component in

Comment: Can you provide more information? Have you added a router-view component? Is there another route that matches the path? Provide more of your code please. Also: Is there a console error?

Answer (score 0):

I *believe* you need the leading slash in your path.

```
{
    path: "/ledger/detail/:ledgerId",
    //...
}
```